# Lookups with Multiple Non-Exact Criteria using INDEX-MATCH - Problem finding nearest values that best meet conedition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make lookups with Multiple Non-Exact Criteria using INDEX-MATCH.
The formual looks like this:

=INDEX(C314:C318;MATCH(1;(D314:D318>=G313)*(E314:E318>=G314);0))

Criterias are: greater or equal to amount X.

Formula works fine, however when using a long list of values, it does not find the best matching value, it finds the first value that matches the criteria.

For example.

Condition 1 is: code "find code equal to 2055516"
Condition 2 is: numerical "find value equal or above 77"
Condition 3 is: alphabetical "find letter equal or greater than H"

In a large dataset where I´ve got many values, it finds only the next best value that matches this criteria. First value that meet that condition would be "80" and "R", however, following values in my dataset, way below, meet much better those criteria with "78" and "I". Problem here is clear I guess.

How can I adapt my formula to look for those much more fitting values that meet my condtions?

Dataset table looks like this:

[image]

The formula should return the name "A, B, C, D, E" of the best maching product.

Comment: What you are finding here is that the  `VLOOKUP`/`HLOOKUP` and `MATCH` Range/Inexact lookups rely on the list being ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a helper column called `Helper` to rank the letters in `Condition 2` alphabetically first using the following formula (drag it down to apply to all rows):

```
=COUNTIF(Condition_2,"<="&Condition_2)
```

then use the following formula to find the best match (although it is an **array formula** it does not need to be confirmed by `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=INDEX(Product1,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,Helper/((Condition_1>=77)/(Condition_2>="H")),1),Helper,0))
```

Replace the **named ranges** in the above formula with the actual ranges in your worksheet.

Replace `,` with `;` as the delimiter in all formulas to suit your system.

[image: solution]

> **EDIT #2**

Based on the new scenario, the problem can be solved by **AGGREGATE** function solely given that the look up value is a number (`EAN`)

[image: Solution2]

The formula in Cell `J2` of my above example is:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,EAN/((DIMENSION=F2)/(LOAD_INDEX>=G2)/(SPEED_INDEX>=H2)),1)
```

Please note the following are all **named ranges** which needs to be replaced with the actual range on your workbook:

- **DIMENSION** being `B2:B8`
- **LOAD_INDEX** being `C2:C8`
- **SPEED_INDEX** being `D2:D8`
- **EAN** being `A2:A8`

If you do not want to show the error `#NUM!` for no matching result, you can use **IFERROR** to return a blank cell as shown in Cell `J3` of my example. The formula is:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,EAN/((DIMENSION=F3)/(LOAD_INDEX>=G3)/(SPEED_INDEX>=H3)),1),"")
```

> **EDIT #3**

Please use the following **array formula** (need to confirm by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**) to find the closest match of `LOAD INDEX` and `SPEED INDEX` with the help of a `Helper` column.

```
{=INDEX(EAN,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,Helper/((LOAD_INDEX/((DIMENSION=G2)/(LOAD_INDEX>=H2)/(SPEED_INDEX>=I2)))=AGGREGATE(15,6,LOAD_INDEX/((DIMENSION=G2)/(LOAD_INDEX>=H2)/(SPEED_INDEX>=I2)),1)),1),Helper/((LOAD_INDEX/((DIMENSION=G2)/(LOAD_INDEX>=H2)/(SPEED_INDEX>=I2)))=AGGREGATE(15,6,LOAD_INDEX/((DIMENSION=G2)/(LOAD_INDEX>=H2)/(SPEED_INDEX>=I2)),1)),0))}
```

[image: Solution3]

The logic is to first find the closest matches to `LOAD INDEX` and then find the closest match to `SPEED LIMIT` from the range with the closest matches to `LOAD INDEX`.

Again if you do not want to show `#NUM!` error for no matching result, you can use **IFERROR** to return the desired result.

Let me know if there is any question. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to write C2 into the first formula? I get always "1"

Comment: Hey again, I tried to add a third condition at the beginning of the formula. The condition should work the same way as the other two, but instead of "equal or greater" it should look for values "equal to". Any possibility to include this into your formula? Example: Condition 1 (equal=): "2056516", Condition 2 (equal or greater than): "107", Condition 3 (Alphabetical, qual or greater than): "T".?

Comment: Hi Terry, nice solution, thanks. The only thing which is still not working is, that the formula does not look for closest match. Lets, say I´m looking for Load index "82" --> then the formula finds the "first match" in the list which can be "88", but far more below in the list there is an load index of "84" or even equal "82". But the rest works like charme :) thanks. Cheers.

Comment: @contiDevTeam thanks for the debugging. I have updated my answer and please see **EDIT #3**. If my or JvdV's solution is working for you, you may mark the answer as the solution to your query by clicking the tick mark under the up-vote and down-vote button.

Answer (score 1):

This might be done through something much smarter, but the following worked for me:

[image]

Formula in `G2`, following the above sample data to return the row with the best match:

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(SMALL(IF(B2:B6-E2>-1,B2:B6-E2+IF(CODE(C2:C6)-CODE(F2)>-1,CODE(C2:C6)-CODE(F2),""),""),1),IF(B2:B6-E2>-1,B2:B6-E2+IF(CODE(C2:C6)-CODE(F2)>-1,CODE(C2:C6)-CODE(F2),""),""),0))
```

> ***Note*** Enter as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

When no criteria matches, it will return an error, you could catch through `IFERROR()`.

Comment: Clever solution. +1 Only thing I would change is changing the 3rd arguments of your `IF` statements to an incredibly large number (e.g. `1E+300`) instead of a blank space. This avoids potential `#VALUE` errors in your array. Probably doesn't matter, but I always like to avoid errors within arrays if possible.

Comment: Ok, I will try. and is it also possible to have the wanted values "77" and "H" entered in two searchfields instead of writing them into the formula?

Comment: @contiDevTeam, check edited answer. It's up to you to replace the "," with ";".

Comment: @JvdV LOL not the , vs. ; issue again!